# How to remove default order of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I stop default sorting inside the ng-repeat for dynamic table data ?
Currently I am getting below order:

> Addr  |   CustomerId  |  Name

but what I want is below ordering:

> CustomerId   |    Name   |   Addr

Any Help would me much appreciated.

**JS:**

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.Customers = [
    { CustomerId: 1, Name: "John Hammond", Addr:'India'
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 2, Name: "Mudassar Khan", Addr:'India'
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 3, Name: "Suzanne Mathews",  Addr:'India'
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 4, Name: "Robert Schidner",  Addr: 'India'
    }
  ];

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr >
    <th ng-repeat="(key,value) in Customers[0]">{{key}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody ng-repeat="c in Customers">
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below way. I hope this below snippet result is showing what you want.

```js
angular.module("aaa",[]).controller('MyController', function ($scope) {        
         $scope.Customers = [
            { CustomerId: 1, Name: "John Hammond", Addr:'India'          
            },
            {
                CustomerId: 2, Name: "Mudassar Khan", Addr:'India'                   
            },
            {
                CustomerId: 3, Name: "Suzanne Mathews",  Addr:'India'                  
            },
            {
                CustomerId: 4, Name: "Robert Schidner",  Addr: 'India'                   
            }
           ];       
           $scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.Customers[0]);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="aaa" ng-controller="MyController">
  <table>
           <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="key in keys"> 
    {{key}}
              </th>               
        </tr>
        <tbody ng-repeat="c in Customers">
            <tr>
              <td ng-repeat="key in keys">{{c[key]}}</td>                   
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So objects in JS are inherently unordered. What you can do is just hard code the keys in the header if that will be fixed for that particular table and then print the values in the respective order.

**Something like this:**

```
<table>
  <tr >
    <th>CustomerId</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Addr</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in Customers">
       <td>{{CustomerId}}</td>
       <td>{{Name}}</td>
       <td>{{c.Addr}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note: I put the ng-repeat on the tr which is probably what you need. I dont think you should put it on the tbody.**

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the sort order of the data or the display order of the columns?

The accepted answer displays the data by the order of the columns as specified, but if you want the data itself sorted then just add a filter to the data like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="c in Customers|orderBy:['CustomerId','Name','Addr']">
```

This sorts the actual data in the list by the fields specified.